# calling a dictionary value as a function argument?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, web-scraping, parameter-passing

I am creating a web scraping function. The cities are stored in each link as a number, which I have stored in a dictionary. I want to call the city name as an argument and return the number value, so that the link can be filled with the appropriate number when I run the function. How can I do this?

```
def get_data(page_index, city):
        towns_dict = {"charleston": 8, "mount pleasant": 49, "john's island": 40, "folly beach": 22,"daniel island": 188, "james island": 37}

        listings = []
        for i in range(1, 22):
                url = f'https://www.marshallwalker.com/listings/index/page:{page_index}/class:1/status:1,3,6/city:{city}/br:0/br_e:0/fba:0/fba_e:0/hba:0/hba_e:0#real-estate-listings'
                page = requests.get(url=url)

                soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
                properties = soup.find_all('div', class_='summary-right')
                for prop in properties:
                        address = prop.select('div.summary-right h3>a')[0].text
                        price = prop.find('div', class_='s-price').text.replace("\t", "")
                        location = prop.select('small.text-muted')[0].text
                        details = prop.find_all("div", class_='s-cut s-common')
                        details = details[1].text.strip()
                        beds = details[:4]
                        baths = details[6:-11]
                        sqft = details[-9:]

                        listings.append([address, location, price, beds, baths, sqft])
                print(listings)
                print()


get_data("i", "charleston")
```

Comment: what is the "i" parameter in your get_data() function call?

Comment: see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Comment: Are you looking for: `url = f'https://www.marshallwalker.../page:{i}/class:1/status:1,3,6/city:{towns_dict[city]}/br:0/...'` ?

Comment: @Captain Caveman
it is the i index to loop through all the pages of listings of a particular city (from the for i in range(1,22)

Comment: You don't need to pass it as parameter if it's just your iterator.

Comment: Please use 4-spacee indentation, 8 spaces causes too much scrolling.

Comment: @Maurice Meyer hey yes this works thank you so much!! now the only problem is that it adds a page of listings to the listings list on each iteration rather than creating a list of the individual listing properties on each iteration ..